# Microdata: moving from microformats to schema.org (example hAtom news markup?)

Tags: html, microdata, schema.org, microformats

**BACKGROUND**

I have been using [microformats](http://microformats.org/) for the past 5 years. I'm switching to the [schema.org](http://schema.org) approach for all new sites because it's — IMHO — a better separation of style and meta info.

In addition all the [major search providers](http://schema.org/docs/faq.html#1) have adopted and now fully support the schema.org approach to microdata.
It's been a pretty painless process finding schema.org equivalents most microdata objects i.e. hCard, hCalendar etc. and am I pleased with the extra possibilities.

**QUESTION**

1. I am looking to find clear examples of the markup in the hAtom/hNews (hFeed)
   flavour can anyone point me in the right direction/give some tips as
   I have searched but been unsuccessful up to now. On schema.org I
   don't see a clear equivalent.
2. We have this handy markup generator http://schema-creator.org/
   for; Person, Product, Event, Organization, Movie, Book and Review,
   but has anyone seen a tool for the creation of the markup of
   schema.org variant of hFeeds.

Answer (score 1):

question 01: Creativeworks -> Blog is schema's equivalent to hatom. 
no clue if anyone's used it or written about it yet.

i'd like to know what about schema.org is better at separation of concerns vs. microformats? schema.org has meta elements within the body element. microformats are html classes and and as such natively support separation. also, every major search provider already provided coverage of microformats and it hasn't decreased. curious, i am.

Comment: Thanks. When I say 'a better separation', what I mean is that `class`es are now exclusively used for styling — their intrinsic purpose, and the `itemprop` attribute exclusively for microdata. Meaning a clearer metadata layer. I also prefer the clarity of the clearly defined start point of the microdata sort using: `itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/MicrodataType"`

Answer (score 1):

You have to choose a page type, like for example http://schema.org/Blog and then add the article/blogposts http://schema.org/BlogPosting

Here is a **very simple** example:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog">
  ...
  <article  itemprop="blogPost" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
    ...
  </article>

  <article  itemprop="blogPost" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
    ...
  </article>
</div>
```

I have tried to implement it in a WordPress theme, perhaps my code will help you: https://github.com/pfefferle/SemPress/